# Predicting values on a curve in R

Tags: r

I am trying to predict the values of a curve in R using this data.

```
   Distance Waggle_time
1       100        9.45
2       200        7.90
3       300        7.04
4       385        6.49
5       400        6.34
6       500        6.01
7       600        5.59
8       700        5.07
9       800        4.79
10      900        4.73
11     1000        4.62
12     1100        4.34
13     1250        4.33
14     1300        4.30
15     1400        4.10
16     1500        4.06
17     2000        3.31
18     2500        3.13
19     3000        2.77
20     3500        2.65
21     4000        2.52
22     4500        2.30
23     5000        2.22
24     6000        1.93
25     7000        1.71
26     8000        1.62
27     8500        1.46
28     9500        1.36
```

I have tried to use the predict function by creating a linear regression model and providing x values that should be used to predict the y values, but this gives me data that is completely wrong. I understand that I am probably completely on the wrong path so any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried plotting your data? that would help a lot to see any trends. To me it seems you will need some transformation before fitting a linear model

Answer (score 1):

A few options are shown below. It's not clear to me if you need help with the model fitting (statistical help) or the prediction of new values (technical help). If the former, you should look at  [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/).

```
df <- structure(list(Distance = c(100L, 200L, 300L, 385L, 400L, 500L, 
600L, 700L, 800L, 900L, 1000L, 1100L, 1250L, 1300L, 1400L, 1500L, 
2000L, 2500L, 3000L, 3500L, 4000L, 4500L, 5000L, 6000L, 7000L, 
8000L, 8500L, 9500L), Waggle_time = c(9.45, 7.9, 7.04, 6.49, 
6.34, 6.01, 5.59, 5.07, 4.79, 4.73, 4.62, 4.34, 4.33, 4.3, 4.1, 
4.06, 3.31, 3.13, 2.77, 2.65, 2.52, 2.3, 2.22, 1.93, 1.71, 1.62, 
1.46, 1.36)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", "3", 
"4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", 
"16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", 
"27", "28"))



splfit <- smooth.spline(x = df$Distance, y = df$Waggle_time, spar = 0.5)
splpred <- data.frame(Distance = seq(min(df$Distance), max(df$Distance), length.out = 100))
splpred$Waggle_time <- predict(splfit, x = newdat$Distance)$y

# lmfit <- glm(Waggle_time ~ Distance, df, family = Gamma(link = "inverse"))
lmfit <- glm(Waggle_time ~ Distance, df, family = inverse.gaussian(link = "1/mu^2"))
glmpred <- splpred
glmpred$Waggle_time <- predict(lmfit, newdata = newdat, type = "response")


plot(Waggle_time ~ Distance, df)
lines(Waggle_time ~ Distance, splpred, col = 2)
lines(Waggle_time ~ Distance, glmpred, col = 3)
legend("topright", legend = c("spline", "inv. Gaussian"), col = 2:3, lty = 1)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help in plotting. What I am looking to do is predict new values based on what I already have, i.e. if Waggle_time is 12, what will Distance be. Which function would be best to do this?

Comment: Well, then you simply would substitute your original df in the places where newdat is called,

Comment: The above doesn't actually work as written. Newdat has to be df, and the length of the prediction has to equal the length of the frame it's going into, so either both need to be 28 or both need to be 100. If you set both to 28 you get a very messy prediction, so I think they're intended to both be 100. Or else newdat has to be a 100 long recieving frame that isn't defined in this code.

Comment: I think what was intended was:
<br> 
newdat <- data.frame(Distance = seq(min(df$Distance), max(df$Distance), length.out = 100)) <br>                                                       
newdat$Waggle_time <- predict(splfit, x = newdat$Distance)$y  <br> 
...<br> 
plot(Waggle_time ~ Distance, df)<br> 
lines(newdat$Waggle_time ~ newdat$Distance, col = 2)<br> 
<br> 
or equiv., and ditto for the other model.

Answer (score 0):

Your data are described better by a log than a linear model. Although you can do a formal model comparison to find this out, it's clear just from plotting the data and some candidate best fit lines:

```
library(tidyverse)

ggplot(df, aes(x = Distance, y = Waggle_time)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  geom_smooth(formula = y ~ log(x), method = "lm", se=F, colour = "blue") +
  geom_smooth(formula = y ~ x, method = "lm", se=F, colour = "red")
```

[image]

As such, you can log transform your data, fit a linear model, use this to predict the your distance values. You can then take the exponent if you'd like the untransformed predictions back.

```
df <- mutate(df, logdistance = log(Distance))
modelfit <- lm(logdistance ~ Waggle_time, df)
to_predict <- tibble(Waggle_time = c(12, 10, 8))

# Predict values with augment
augment(modelfit, newdata = to_predict) %>%
  mutate(truefitted = exp(.fitted))
```

Output, with predictions of `Distance` on your original scale in the column `truefitted`:

```
  Waggle_time .fitted .se.fit truefitted
        <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>      <dbl>
1          12    2.74  0.116        15.5
2          10    3.90  0.0885       49.6
3           8    5.07  0.0623      159.
```